# XOR cryptographic algorithm not working for > 54 chars

Tags: python, string, encryption, random

I recently began to play around with cryptography after playing with Project Euler [Problem 59](https://projecteuler.net/problem=59), and I made a basic XOR cryptography system. In this case the concatentation of your output and a random key are made and saved to a text file (only as a test, I will make it better once I've fixed this bug), but I've noticed that certain messages do not encrypt or decrypt correctly. I've narrowed this down to messages of length > 54. My code is as follows:

```
#encrypt.py

import random

msg = raw_input("Enter your message: ")
out = ""
key = ""

for i in xrange(len(msg)):
    key += chr(random.randint(0,255))

k = 0

for char in msg:
    out += chr(ord(msg[k]) ^ ord(key[k]))
    k += 1

print "\nYour output is:", out
print "Your key is:", key

raw_input()

with open("output.txt","r+") as f:
    f.truncate()
    f.write(out+key)
```

And decryption:

```
#decrypt.py

import sys

if not len(sys.argv) > 1: exit()

with open(sys.argv[1],"r+") as f:
    content = f.read()

msg, key = content[:len(content)/2], content[len(content)/2:]

out = ""

k = 0

for char in msg:
    out += chr(ord(char) ^ ord(key[k]))
    k += 1

print out
raw_input()
```

For longer messages (than 54 chars), when they are decrypted they will give a string of random characters. Does anyone have an idea as to why this happens?

Comment: `for x in range(255): print chr(x)` prints mostly bad characters

Comment: It doesn't seem specifically wrong, but your for loops are different, and a little odd (to me) in the encryption and decryption programs.  Also, if the error happens at 54 characters, look for the numbers 54 and 108 in the code, libraries, and tools you use.  E.g. if your text editor automatically wraps text at 108 characters, you would add some control characters and get garbled output after 54 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since making characters out of random bits is likely to produce characters that look ugly on the screen, you can try hex-encoding the output before printing it.

```python
#encrypt.py

import random

msg = raw_input("Enter your message: ")
out = ""
key = ""

for i in xrange(len(msg)):
    key += chr(random.randint(0,255))

k = 0

for char in msg:
    out += chr(ord(msg[k]) ^ ord(key[k]))
    k += 1
out = ":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in out)
key = ":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in key)
print "\nYour output is:", out
print "Your key is:", key

raw_input()

with open("output.txt","w+") as f:
    f.truncate()
    f.write(out+key)
```

Then for decryption, you have to remove the colons and hex-decode before you can continue with regular decryption.

```python
#decrypt.py

import sys

if not len(sys.argv) > 1: exit()

with open(sys.argv[1],"r+") as f:
    content = f.read()

content = content.replace(':', '')
msg, key = content[:len(content)/2], content[len(content)/2:]
msg = msg.decode('hex')
key = key.decode('hex')
out = ""

k = 0

for char in msg:
    out += chr(ord(char) ^ ord(key[k]))
    k += 1

print out
raw_input()
```

At the console, the results look like this:

```
$ python encrypt.py           
Enter your message: onetwothreefourfivesixseveneightnineteneleventwelvethirteen
Your output is: 7f:09:d0:8c:2e:1a:e0:a0:84:e7:bf:3b:e8:cc:f3:4e:35:e4:4f:20:c8:00:72:9d:f0:bc:de:54:88:30:a6:3d:93:3f:c1:6d:46:4a:68:ca:96:2e:16:50:43:0f:30:fa:27:f3:f2:8d:35:4b:6a:11:cc:02:04
Your key is: 10:67:b5:f8:59:75:94:c8:f6:82:da:5d:87:b9:81:28:5c:92:2a:53:a1:78:01:f8:86:d9:b0:31:e1:57:ce:49:fd:56:af:08:32:2f:06:af:fa:4b:60:35:2d:7b:47:9f:4b:85:97:f9:5d:22:18:65:a9:67:6a
$ cat output.txt 
7f:09:d0:8c:2e:1a:e0:a0:84:e7:bf:3b:e8:cc:f3:4e:35:e4:4f:20:c8:00:72:9d:f0:bc:de:54:88:30:a6:3d:93:3f:c1:6d:46:4a:68:ca:96:2e:16:50:43:0f:30:fa:27:f3:f2:8d:35:4b:6a:11:cc:02:0410:67:b5:f8:59:75:94:c8:f6:82:da:5d:87:b9:81:28:5c:92:2a:53:a1:78:01:f8:86:d9:b0:31:e1:57:ce:49:fd:56:af:08:32:2f:06:af:fa:4b:60:35:2d:7b:47:9f:4b:85:97:f9:5d:22:18:65:a9:67:6a
$ python decrypt.py output.txt
onetwothreefourfivesixseveneightnineteneleventwelvethirteen
```

Comment: This worked, as I'm pretty sure the problem was caused by backspace characters that I didn't want.